# SQL optimize inner join (Inner join with union and possible use of subquery)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm having two tables -- Test, Child which contains versioned data. 
Description about columns:

```
TEST, CHILD Table
ID - Record id (not unique due to multiple versions)
MODSTAMP - Timestamp at which record is inserted
DELETEDDATE - Timestamp at which record is deleted; NULL value means record is not deleted yet.
COMPOSITE KEY = {ID, MODSTAMP}

CHILD Table
DATA - Foreign key that references Test(ID)
DATA2 - Foreign key that references Test(ID)
```

I am working on a requirement where the records are selected between two timestamps - $FROMTIME and $TOTIME. I am able to select the records on the Test table by running a self-join.

```
SELECT v.id, v.modstamp FROM test v
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Id, MAX(modstamp) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM test where modstamp >= '2017-08-16 15:08:04 +00:00' and modstamp <= '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00' GROUP BY Id) g 
ON v.Id = g.Id 
AND v.modstamp = g.MaxDateTime where v.deleteddate is null
```

I am also required to select the latest version of the corresponding child records (without any duplicate record id and thus the group by clause) for which the parent records are selected. My application holds the results from the above query and runs the following query to select the valid child record for every value ['aaa', 'bbb']:

```
 SELECT v.* FROM child v
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT id, MAX(modstamp) AS MaxDateTime
        FROM child where (data = ? or data is null) and modstamp <= '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00' GROUP BY id
            UNION
        SELECT id, MAX(modstamp) AS MaxDateTime
        FROM child where (data2 = ? or data2 is null) and modstamp <= '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00' GROUP BY id
        ) g 
    ON v.id = g.id 
    AND v.modstamp = g.MaxDateTime
```

Can anyone suggest how to optimize this solution? With the current approach, if n parent records are selected, there will be n inner joins that will be running.

This is the query that is intended for join but throws 'Multi-part identifier not found error'. Any other ways to rewrite the query?
-- intended query

```
SELECT v.* FROM child v
    INNER JOIN (select distinct(id) from DATA) D
    ON v.id = D.id
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT id, MAX(modstamp) AS MaxDateTime
        FROM child where (data = d.id or data is null) and modstamp <= '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00' GROUP BY id
            UNION
        SELECT id, MAX(modstamp) AS MaxDateTime
        FROM child where (data2 = d.id or data2 is null) and modstamp <= '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00' GROUP BY id
        ) g 
    ON v.id = g.id 
    AND v.modstamp = g.MaxDateTime;
```

**Sample info to run the script:**

```
Test
| ID | MODSTAMP | DELETEDDATE |

Child
| ID | DATA | DATA2 | MODSTAMP | DELETEDDATE |
```

Script (using SQL Server):

```
drop table test;
drop table child;

CREATE TABLE TEST(ID VARCHAR(20), modstamp DATETIMEOFFSET, deleteddate DATETIMEOFFSET);
insert into test values('aaa', '2017-08-16 15:08:04 +00:00', null);
insert into test values('aaa', '2017-08-16 16:08:04 +00:00', null);
insert into test values('aaa', '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00', null);
insert into test values('aaa', '2017-08-16 18:08:04 +00:00', '2017-08-16 18:08:04 +00:00');
insert into test values('bbb', '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00', null);

CREATE TABLE CHILD(ID VARCHAR(20), DATA VARCHAR(10), DATA2 VARCHAR(10), modstamp DATETIMEOFFSET, deleteddate DATETIMEOFFSET);
insert into CHILD values('1', 'aaa', null, '2017-08-16 15:08:04 +00:00', null);
insert into CHILD values('1', null, 'bbb', '2017-08-16 16:08:04 +00:00', null);
insert into CHILD values('1', null, null, '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00', null);
insert into CHILD values('2', 'aaa', null, '2017-08-16 15:08:04 +00:00', null);
insert into CHILD values('3', null, null, '2017-08-16 15:08:04 +00:00', null);
```

Comment: Are you looking for a shorter way to write this? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking to optimize the selection of child records for the list of parent record ids ('aaa', 'bbb').

Comment: row_number will be faster than the max aggregate.

Comment: Somehow I don't understand the issue: you say you want to select records between two dates, but select only the max(modstamp). Furthermore you write that you hold the records of the first query and with this execute the second query by passing parameters... so, unless you want to redesign the whole process - what is the expected result? If you want to skip this "evaluate the parent records and pass them to the second query" you could simply use a cte and join it against your child table...

Comment: @Tyron78 Using a CTE and join on the child table is wrong as this contains the versioned data. Imagine picking up the latest record during the given timestamp range as multiple versions of the same record ids could exist.

Answer (score 0):

You're query looks good. I wouldn't call the following query optimized, but an alternative way would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY modstamp)
FROM child
WHERE (data = ? OR data IS NULL OR data2 = ? OR data2 IS NULL) AND modstamp <= '2017-08-16 17:08:04 +00:00'
) AS a where rownum = 1
```